# How to avoid overloading a method with Scala types for generic Spark RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a method like this:

```
def save[T](index: String, data: RDD[T]) = {
    spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
    // ...do other stuff...
}
```

but I cannot compile it as I keep on get:

```
Error:(42, 32) overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  [A <: Product](data: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  [A <: Product](rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[A])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (T)
      spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(data.asInstanceOf[T]),
```

I tried different solutions but I could not make it work. Any idea?

Comment: Just to check how are you invoking save method & what value are you passing as T

Comment: The `RDD` is carrying information included in my case classes (no inheritance, just plain case classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `save[T]` Should be sub type of `T <: Product : TypeTag`. Please check below.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def save[T <: Product: TypeTag](index: String, data: RDD[T]) = {
     | spark.createDataFrame[T](data)
     | }
save: [T <: Product](index: String, data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Comment: actually I have already tried that but I didn't use the `implicit`

Comment: yes got what I did wrong, mine was only: `[T <: Product]` but a case class is extended as `extends Product` but needs TypeTag cos of the erasure type. Thank you